# How to execute get command in redis cluster mode using python?

Tags: python, redis

I want to perform the following scenario on redis using python.

Using command line:
1) redis-cli -c
2) redis_prompt >> get some_string

I tried using redis and rediscluster modules, but with no luck. Below are the codes that i tried: 
1)

```
r = redis.Redis(host='123.123.123.123', port=6379, db=0)
r.get('some srting')
```

Got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 880, in get
    return self.execute_command('GET', name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 573, in execute_command
    return self.parse_response(connection, command_name, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 585, in parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 582, in read_response
    raise response
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: MOVED 9442 172.16.176.36:6380
```

2)

```
from rediscluster import StrictRedisCluster
startup_nodes = [{"host": "123.123.123.123", "port": "7000"}]
rc_readonly = StrictRedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes, decode_responses=True, readonly_mode=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rediscluster\client.py", line 181, in __init__
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rediscluster\connection.py", line 353, in __init__
    **connection_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rediscluster\connection.py", line 141, in __init__
    self.nodes.initialize()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rediscluster\nodemanager.py", line 240, in initialize
    raise RedisClusterException("Redis Cluster cannot be connected. Please provide at least one reachable node.")
rediscluster.exceptions.RedisClusterException: Redis Cluster cannot be connected. Please provide at least one reachable node.
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: The port is 6379 (in section 1) ? or 7000 (in section 2)

Comment: @Jacky i tried with both ports 6379 and 7000 for both section 1 and 2.

Comment: you need to contact to the redis administrator to make sure which port to use. And I want to know what exception raised if setting port to 6379 in section 2. Note that setting port to a number instead of string.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so this error means one of the following:

- In these lines of code (1):

  ```
  r = redis.Redis(host='123.123.123.123', port=6379, db=0)

  r.get('some srting')
  ```

  you try to fetch the key "some sting" from host `123.123.123.123` and
  port `6379`. The error `redis.exceptions.ResponseError: MOVED 9442
  172.16.176.36:6380` means that this key lies in `172.16.176.36:6380`. So try to connect with .`/redis-cli -c -p 6380` in this node and then
  execute `CLUSTER GETKEYSINSLOT 6380 3` to see if this key is actually
  here.
- From (2) this error: `rediscluster.exceptions.RedisClusterException: Redis Cluster cannot be connected. Please provide at least one reachable node` means that something is wrong with the cluster. Maybe, you have not made correct the initialization.

  First in `/home/{{user}}/redis-yourversion/utils/create-cluster` you
  will find `create-cluster.sh`. Set up port and host and nodes and then
  execute `./create-cluster start` `./create-cluster-create`. But first you
  have to start redis server in cluster mode. Go to redis.conf and in
  the configuration parameters you will see `cluster-enabled no`. Set up
  to yes. After this you must run `./redis-server ../redis.conf` (give
  the path for redis.conf). If cluster enabled is correct you will see    `Running in cluster mode`

Important thing to remember:

The parameter -c in terminal means that redis nodes can execute the redirections and find the correct node that the key belongs without MOVED errors. If you have a driver suppose in python to manipulate the nodes and fetch keys or whatever you must manage these redirections by yourself.